# Animating matplotlib contour plot with moviepy

Tags: python, matplotlib, moviepy

I am trying to animate a matplotlib contour plot with moviepy. I am happy with the individual frames produced by matplotlib. But the resulting video has much lower resolution, to the point where the labels and annotations are tricky to read. This is not a problem I have had with previous moviepy animations from matplotlib figures, or any of the examples provided in the moviepy documentation.

The code I am using follows the examples in the moviepy documentation quite closely:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import moviepy.editor as mpy
from moviepy.video.io.bindings import mplfig_to_npimage

duration = 20

def make_frame(t):

    i = np.int32(model.time_steps * t / duration)
    fig, ax = model.plot_frame(i)
    frame = mplfig_to_npimage(fig)
    plt.close('all')
    return frame

animation = mpy.VideoClip(make_frame, duration=duration)
animation.write_videofile("movie.mp4", fps=24, codec='libx264')
```

`model` is my own class which contains all of the data to be rendered.

I know rendering the whole figure and closing it each time is clunky - there are some other issues that make that tricky to avoid at the minute, and it's further down the list of things to improve.

I'm guessing I might need to pass some extra arguments to `ffmpeg` in `animation.write_videofile`? But I am currently stumped and would appreciate any pointers anyone might have?

Cheers,

Comment: What is the frame resolution like? maybe check the shape of `frame`or plot it as an image and compare visually with the original plot. I have had this problem before but just accepted that the quality was going to be bad, I hope there is a solution!

Comment: frame has shape (504,504,3). I'll have a look at how frame looks when plotted as an image, thanks!

Comment: If you want to test if the issue is the compression, I would write out (a subset of) your animation as a gif, or some other loss-less compression format, e.g. using `animation.write_videofile("movie.gif")`.